# Android with AWS, Dynamodb, getCredentials() null object reference

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I was following the tutorial on the AWS website on their dynamodb.(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html)

However when I used the mapper.save(object) function, I get an error that says:

`[Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider.getCredentials()' on a null object reference]`

below is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
    public AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                this.getApplicationContext(), // Context
                "identity_pool_id", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
        );




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void saveFile(View view) {
        AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);
        View name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        View number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setTitle(name.toString());
        book.setAuthor("Charles Dickens");
        book.setPrice(1299);
        book.setIsbn(number.toString());
        book.setHardCover(false);
        mapper.save(book);
    }
}
```

The book class is just the copy paste from the website

Comment: i bet on NetworkOnMainThreadException ... (of course internally(inside amazon API) and "eated" by other calls) ... also: `View name = (TextView) findViewById(...)` make no sens  `findViewById` already return `View` ... using `View.toString()` also make no sens - use `TextView.getText()` ... so better: `final String name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).getText();` (of course it may throw NPE but if layout is ok - it shouldn't)

Comment: @Selvin, I don't think the view is the issue tho, but thanks, i'll edit the view. as per the first problem, I don't really understand what you mean. Any ideas on how i might solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` you initialized inside `onCreate()` is a local instance instead of the intended class level one. Please remove `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` in `onCreate()`.